# Detecting Embed URLs Within post_content

Tags: filters, embed, globals, oembed

I need to change the way WP outputs html when given an embed URL within the content. Example content within the WP editor:

```
This is standard content and will be wrapped in a 'p' tag. But check out this cool vid:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JJv4TvURj4

This will be output as another 'p' tag. The above URL will be turned into an iFrame.
```

The goal is for the client to input something simple like that, and change the way wordpress outputs it on the page. I have been using the `oembed_dataparse` filter to good effect so far, but **I would like to take the video URL and pass it to another function outside of the filter**. How can I do that?

My initial approach was to use a global variable. Here's my abridged filter code:

```
add_filter('oembed_dataparse', 'modal_embed', 10, 3);
function modal_embed($html, $data, $url) {
    // This is supposed to store the URL globally so I can access it 
    // outside this filter.
    global $video_url;
    $video_url = $url;

    $custom_output = "<div class='video'>$html</div>"; // Just an example. 
    return $custom_output;
}
```

The code I create as `$custom_output` works just fine and is displayed on the page. The issue is that I'm not getting access to `$video_url` globally as I expected. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, got it. I just dug around in wp core a bit and found the function they use to grab autodetcts. WP uses the php `preg_replace_callback` function within the WP `autoembed` function. Here is the code, as seen in `wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php`:

```
/**
     * Passes any unlinked URLs that are on their own line to {@link WP_Embed::shortcode()} for potential embedding.
     *
     * @uses WP_Embed::autoembed_callback()
     *
     * @param string $content The content to be searched.
     * @return string Potentially modified $content.
     */
    function autoembed( $content ) {
        return preg_replace_callback( '|^\s*(https?://[^\s"]+)\s*$|im', array( $this, 'autoembed_callback' ), $content );
    }
```

Since i'm only planning on the client inputting one video per post I use the `preg_match` function along with this same RegEx patter to achieve what I want:

```
function embed_url_lookup() {
    if (!have_posts()) return false;

    the_post(); // necessary to use get_the_content()

    $reg = preg_match('|^\s*(https?://[^\s"]+)\s*$|im', get_the_content(), $matches);

    if (!$reg) return false;

    return trim($matches[0]);

} // end embed_url_looku
```

This will find the first autoembed url and return it.