# Add video from youtube in post

Tags: videos

I need to add video from youtube in certain place on my page.
I added link in post like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXGR7puGRpg` (post contains only this link), and then I added code on my page

```
<?php
$post_id_63 = get_post( $post_id = 63 );
if($post_id_63) {
    $post_id_63_content = $post_id_63->post_content;
    echo $post_id_63_content;
}
?>
```

but I get just text link on my page, not video. What did I do wrong? How to fix it and make it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is overview how you can make it working:

First with below code you can detect youtube URL for details [Please read](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114656/detecting-embed-urls-within-post-content):

```
$reg = preg_match('|^\s*(https?://[^\s"]+)\s*$|im', $post_id_63->post_content, $matches);

 if (!$reg) return false;

 $url =  trim($matches[0]); // youtube video url 

 echo wp_oembed_get($url); // this will return youtube vidoe
```

For details please read: [Wp_oembed_get](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get)

we need to use `wp_oembed_get` to make URL into video from post content

Thanks!

Comment: I am glad that it makes some sense :)